# How to give Emacs-started-by-icon-click the same environment as Emacs-started-from-Unix-shell?

Tags: osx, environment, system-environment

On my Mac laptop, I can start Emacs in several ways, including (1) clicking on an icon on the dock, or (2) running

```
% emacs
```

from the Terminal app.

These two ways of launching Emacs produce instances of Emacs that run differently, because they have different settings for their environment variables.

How can I give the instance of Emacs that I start by clicking on an icon the "same"<sup>1</sup> environment as that of an instance of Emacs started from the Unix shell command-line (as described above) right after the parent shell is initialized?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Well, the two environments cannot be *exactly* the same, because there are some environment settings, such as the value of the `$$` parameter, that are specific to the respective processes.  So, when I say that two environments are "the same", I mean that they agree on all the settings for which such agreement is possible in principle.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a package called **[exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell)** that was made to solve this problem.  By default, it'll try to figure out `PATH` and `MANPATH` from your shell setup, but you can customize the variable [`exec-path-from-shell-variables`](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell/blob/master/exec-path-from-shell.el#L85-L89) to pull in more environment variables.  You'll need to figure out for yourself which environment variables matter to you.

```lisp
;; note env vars of interest
(dolist (var '("SSH_AUTH_SOCK" "SSH_AGENT_PID" "GPG_AGENT_INFO" "LANG" "LC_CTYPE" "NIX_SSL_CERT_FILE" "NIX_PATH"))
  (add-to-list 'exec-path-from-shell-variables var))
;; set env vars in emacs
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

Comment: The problem with an emacs solution like the above is that it is disconnected from the rest of your system: there is no single source of truth. Every time you make a change in your environment for shell purposes, you will have to make (or at least think about)  the corresponding change for emacs purposes - and vice versa.

Comment: An alternative is the way aquamacs does this - it pipes the shell command env to a file and then parses it. https://github.com/aquamacs-emacs/aquamacs-emacs/blob/aquamacs3/aquamacs/src/site-lisp/macosx/mac-extra-functions.el see functions  mac-read-environment-vars* It is more complex but does the whole environment

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a tutorial about this](https://roamingbytes.substack.com/p/emacs-on-macos-preserving-the-correct-environment-1735d2e8cb88). exec-path-from-shell can significantly increase Emacs's startup time. I prefer the Doom Emacs approach: save the shell environment to a file, and load it when Emacs starts. My article shows how to do that.

Comment: The ```emacs-plus``` uses the [injected path](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus#injected-path) approach to get same thing. May be added to your tutorial.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. Yes, I also noticed that emacs-plus injects `PATH` by modifying `Emacs.app/Contents/Info.plist`. I will add a note to my tutorial. Though there are other env variables that are useful in Emacs. For instance, I use [Keychain](https://www.funtoo.org/Funtoo:Keychain) to avoid typing ssh key passwords. `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` changes on every boot, so it's easier to update it with a script.