# How to run yarn in a bash script from emacs?

Tags: shell-command, bash, environment

I have a bash script like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/src/program && rm -rf node_modules && yarn
```

When I invoke this script by executing `(shell-command "bash ~/src/helper/script.sh")` it stumbles on `yarn` and returns exit code 127. Also, it successfully executes every command before `yarn`.

I also tried `yarn install`, `bash -c "yarn install"` with no avail.

When I run the script from emacs *shell* buffer or from an external bash, it executes successfully. I also made the script executable, but it didn't help.

How to easily run a bash script or an emacs function from an Org Mode file to remove a directory and invoke `yarn install` to populate that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with environment variables where your interactive bash session has a different `PATH` than your emacs session.  In your interactive bash session (where yarn is working), try the following:

```bash
which yarn
echo $PATH
```

Then, inside emacs, start an elisp repl via <kbd>M-x ielm</kbd>, and try this:

```lisp
(getenv "PATH")
```

You may notice that the path for yarn is missing for emacs.  There are a few ways to fix this, but the most direct way may be to use [`setenv`](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/System-Environment#command-setenv-variable-optional-value-substitute) to add the missing path to `PATH`.

```lisp
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/path/for/yarn/bin"))
```

Of course, replace `":/path/for/yarn/bin"` with a path that's appropriate for your own system.

If you need more environment variables, you might be interested in this answer to another environment-related question.  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73665/37580

Comment: It works, thank you! Also, thank you for introducing the Elisp REPL to me! Now I am confused how to exit it. :-)

Comment: You can just kill the ielm buffer using C-x k.